# Is there any way to create firebase authentication credential for already registered user without authentication?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I uploaded bulk user data from other fire store database. But authentication details of those users which we want for firebase authentication service is not accessible? The firebase authentication needs to be added to already registered user. How to do it?

I tried some work arounds but editing document ID/User Id in firebase auth is not possible. It creates default one and it should be connected to our existing collection. But I need old document Id of every user for user reference in my collection so mapping new id to old one is not possible.

I want to know some methods to edit authentication user ID or giving custom user ID while creating authenticating new user.

Comment: What do you mean by "But authentication details of those users which we want for firebase authentication service is not accessible"?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know some methods to [...] give custom user ID while creating
> authenticating new user.

You need to use the Admin SDK, which provides a `createUser()` method that allows you to create a new Firebase user **with a user ID you provide**. Read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?authuser=0#create_a_user) for more details ("Create a user" section).

The easiest way to run the Admin SDK is to use a Cloud Function. In this function you can read the existing users documents from Firestore (to get the existing users IDs and details) and create the users in the Authentication service.

*If you add details of your Firestore `users` collection in your question I could propose some code for such a Cloud Function.*

---

Another approach would be to use the [`auth:import`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-import) command of the Firebase CLI but you would first need to export your Firestore collection containing the users data to a CSV or JSON file. Using a Cloud Function and the Admin SDK is much easier.